# OTA for FreeRTOS for device in deep sleep from AWS

Tags: mqtt, esp32, aws-iot, freertos, esp-idf

### Background

I have a small battery powered system running on freeRTOS. I need to periodically run OTA updates, as per any proper internet connected device. The problem is that, being battery powered, the device spends 99.9% of it's life in deep sleep.

When the device is awake, it's possible to post an OTA update from AWS, by publishing to the device's OTA/update topic. From the console, you can only use QOS = 0. But from inside, say a lambda, I believe it's possible to use QOS = 1.

```
{
"state": {
        "desired": {
            "ota_url":"https://s3-ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/my.awesome.bucket/signed_binary_v21.bin"
        }
    }
}
```

### Questions

1. How can I modify this approach to successfully update a device that sleeps for 15 minutes at a time, and wakes for maybe 10 s. During the waking period, it sends a message. Is there some way of leaving the desired OTA/update in the shadow that somehow is included in the response from AWS. I've not managed to figure out how shadows really work. OR can you specify a retry period and time to keep trying perhaps?
2. Is this approach essentially consistent with the most recent best practice from a security perspective : signed binary, encrypted flash & secure boot etc.

Many thanks.

Comment: OTA can be done as download too

Comment: @Juraj cool. Would you mind posting an answer with more detail!

Comment: I know how to do it with Arduino, but don't know how to do it with IDF. but for battery powered system which sleeps most of the time a update download is the right way

Comment: @Juraj that would be really useful if you wouldn't mind posting. Idf isn't all that big of a deal.

Comment: Arduino core has an Updater class which does the OTA update a different way then the SDK way. Then around Updater there are 3 libraries which use it. ArduinoOTA library for upload from Arduino IDE, ESP8266HTTPUpdateServer library which allows upload over a web page and third is the ESP8266httpUpdate library which handles a download of the update from a specified server. here is the example:  https://github.com/esp8266/Arduino/blob/master/libraries/ESP8266httpUpdate/examples/httpUpdate/httpUpdate.ino  All this uses the Arduino core and other Arduino libraries so it can't be used with IDF.

Answer (score 1):

IDF comes with an OTA example that is pretty straight forward.  As suggested in the comments on your question, the example downloads the firmware update, and it will automatically revert to the previous image if the updated version has errors that cause a reset.  This is the operative part of the example:

```
extern const uint8_t server_cert_pem_start[] asm("_binary_ca_cert_pem_start");
extern const uint8_t server_cert_pem_end[] asm("_binary_ca_cert_pem_end");
esp_err_t _ota_http_event_handler(esp_http_client_event_t* evt);
#define FIRMWARE_UPGRADE_URL "https://yourserver.com/somefolder/somefirmware.bin"

void simple_ota_task(void* pvParameter)
{
    esp_http_client_config_t config = {
        .url = FIRMWARE_UPGRADE_URL,
        .cert_pem = (char*)server_cert_pem_start,
        .event_handler = _ota_http_event_handler,
    };
    esp_err_t ret = esp_https_ota(&config);
    if (ret == ESP_OK)
        ESP_LOGW("ota", "Upgrade success");
    else 
        ESP_LOGE(TAG, "Upgrade failure");

    esp_restart();
}

void foo()
{
    // after initializing WiFi, create a task to execute OTA:
    //
    xTaskCreate(&simple_ota_task, "ota_task", 8192, NULL, 5, NULL);
}

// event handler callback referenced above, it has no functional purpose
// just dumps info log output
esp_err_t _ota_http_event_handler(esp_http_client_event_t* evt)
{
    switch (evt->event_id) {
    case HTTP_EVENT_ERROR:
        ESP_LOGD(TAG, "HTTP_EVENT_ERROR");
        break;
    case HTTP_EVENT_ON_CONNECTED:
        ESP_LOGD(TAG, "HTTP_EVENT_ON_CONNECTED");
        break;
    case HTTP_EVENT_HEADER_SENT:
        ESP_LOGD(TAG, "HTTP_EVENT_HEADER_SENT");
        break;
    case HTTP_EVENT_ON_HEADER:
        ESP_LOGD(TAG, "HTTP_EVENT_ON_HEADER, key=%s, value=%s", evt->header_key, evt->header_value);
        break;
    case HTTP_EVENT_ON_DATA:
        ESP_LOGD(TAG, "HTTP_EVENT_ON_DATA, len=%d", evt->data_len);
        break;
    case HTTP_EVENT_ON_FINISH:
        ESP_LOGD(TAG, "HTTP_EVENT_ON_FINISH");
        break;
    case HTTP_EVENT_DISCONNECTED:
        ESP_LOGD(TAG, "HTTP_EVENT_DISCONNECTED");
        break;
    }
    return ESP_OK;
}
```

To setup embedding the cert, obtain the public key by examining the SSL cert for the site on which the bin file will reside, with a web browser, save it, then convert it to Base64, aka PEM format. (I used some web page.)  In my case I created a directory at the same level as the /main directory, called /server_certs, and saved the Base64 conversion in that directory as ca_cert.pem.  (That was way too pedantic, wasn't it?)

Then added these lines to CMakeFiles.txt in the /main directory:

```
# Embed the server root certificate into the final binary
set(COMPONENT_EMBED_TXTFILES ${IDF_PROJECT_PATH}/server_certs/ca_cert.pem)
register_component()
```

The thing that was unclear to me was how to determine that a newer version is available, if there is a built-in way I couldn't discern it, and did not want to download the update for nothing, ever.  So I rolled my own, embedded a version string in the firmware, created a WebAPI entry point on my server that returns the current version (both maintained by hand until I can think of a better way... that I feel like implementing) and call the OTA functionality when the strings don't match.  It looks a lot like this:

```
// The WebAPI returns data in JSON format, 
// so if a method returns a string it is quoted.
#define FW_VERSION "\"00.09.015\""

// the HTTP request has just completed, payload stored in recv_buf
//
// tack a null terminator using an index maintained by the HTTP transfer
recv_buf[pos + 1] = 0;
// test for success
if (strncmp(recv_buf, "HTTP/1.1 200 OK", 15) == 0)
{
    // find the end of the headers
    char *p = strstr(recv_buf, "\r\n\r\n");
    if (p)
    {
        ESP_LOGI("***", "version: %s  content %s", FW_VERSION, (p + 4));
        if (strcmp((p + 4), FW_VERSION) > 0)
        {
            // execute OTA task
            foo();
        }
        else
        {
            // Assumes the new version has run far enough to be 
            // considered working, commits the update.  It doesn't
            // hurt anything to call this any number of times.
            esp_ota_mark_app_valid_cancel_rollback();
        }
    }
}
```

If you're not using the CMake/Ninja build tools, consider checking it out, it's way, way faster than the MingW32-based tool set.

Answer (score 0):

As you have mentioned, you do not fully understand how shadows work, let me explain how using shadows may fit in scenario similar to yours.

Normally, a device that sleeps for long and wakes up for a short duration, usually makes a request to device shadow at wake up. If the shadow contains

> {"state": {"desired":{"ota_url": "xxx", "do_ota": true, ...}}},

In this case, device should initiate ota update code inside device.

Further, the approach mentioned here has nothing to do with security and best practices (signed binary, encrypted flash and secure boot). All these three things should be handled by ota update program. Shadows are only used to indicate that there is a ota update available. Using shadow help you avoid making unnecessary GET Request to OTA server, in turn saving precious power and compute resources.